"Policy match error" when applying custom IPSec policy

Following these tutorials, configuring PEAP User Certificate authentication: 1, 2, 3
Applying this IKEv2 Security Baseline
Configuring the client with this command: Set-VpnConnectionIPsecConfiguration -ConnectionName "MY_VPN_CONNECTION" -AuthenticationTransformConstants GCMAES128 -CipherTransformConstants GCMAES128 -DHGroup Group14 -EncryptionMethod GCMAES128 -IntegrityCheckMethod SHA256 -PFSgroup ECP256 -Force

I receive a policy match error when attempting to connect. If I revert to defaults (Set-VpnConnectionIPsecConfiguration -ConnectionName "MY_VPN_CONNECTION" -RevertToDefault -Force and Set-VpnServerConfiguration -RevertToDefault; Restart-Service RemoteAccess -PassThru), all works. Fresh Server 2022 box, and a Windows 11 22H2 client.

Active Directory, NPS servers, and the CA were already in-place before I deployed Always-on-VPN.
Only client event log I can find is a generic RasClient (event ID 20227) with a failure code of 13868.
NPS servers show no issues (whether in the event log or INXXXX.log).
VPN server gives a generic RemoteAccess (event ID 20255) log The following error occurred in the Point to Point Protocol module on port: VPN2-1, UserName: foo@bar. Policy match error

I dug a bit deeper and did a netsh trace on the client:
Microsoft-Windows-RRAS/EventID(6003)
Lines 14-17 indicate failure: https://pastebin.com/itm7HZmU
Microsoft-Windows-RRAS/EventID(6001)
Line 24 seems to be after 6003, showing a similar error: https://pastebin.com/yZHPMcCV
Where else can I look to determine the root cause? Or, perhaps, am I going the wrong direction with this method of hardening?
